# index on partitioned table doesn't enhance performance with a function in where clause

Tags: database, oracle, sqlperformance, database-indexes

I have this query

```
select col1,col2, x.id pk 
/*+ INDEX (some_index_on_col4)*/
from tbl1 y
,tbl2 x
where col2 = 'some_value' and col3 = 'U'
and x.col4 = dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(y.PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )
;
```

the query is very slow, and when I explain the plan, it shows that the index is not used but a full table scan is used instead, if I remove

```
dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(y.PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )
```

and say instead

```
x.col4 = 3456
```

it's working fine, how can I enhance this?

N.B. : tbl2 is partitioned

Comment: You may also post execution plans for both queries as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: When you change it to `x.col4 = 3456` then Oracle knows there will only be one x.col4 value of interest (3456) and so can clearly use the index.  With `dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(y.PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )` there could be many different x.col4 values that are selected - maybe even **all** of them - so the optimizer may decide a full scan is preferable,

Comment: actually there was no match and that is why the index wasn't used as a full scan was performed any way ... but when there is a match, the index is used

Comment: The hint would go after the word "select"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there was no match and that is why the index wasn't used as a full scan was performed any way ... but when there is a match, the index is used

Answer (score 1):

One obvious difference (and offen cause of *not using index*) is that the result of `dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(y.PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )`is VARCHAR, not a `NUMBER` as `3456`.

So if possible transform it with `to_number`.

But you will not get the same plan as for `3456` becaouse this is constant; the original query uses `y.PK_DATA`.

Comment: thank u , it helped a little, but the execution plan is still saying that it is making a full scan not using the index